# Older scifi movie about marooned ship in medieval type area

Tags: story-identification, movie

Saw part of it in the 80's, think it was made in the 70's. Everyone in this story is human. A group is marooned and find an older saucer type ship stuck in a tree that has also been marooned but for a longer time. Someone is living in it and the ship is good all except for a power source. His comrade disappeared a long time ago and holds the key to getting the tree ship going.

They go in search of him and find themselves in a castle talking to the local ruler. He knows of the person they are looking for. He had him locked up in the dungeon for failing to live up to his promise of offering "the power of lightning". When the group get put in the dungeon they find the skeleton of the person they are looking for and the guy from the tree ship breaks down after learning his fate.

At this point I had to go to bed and never learned how it ended and do not know the name. Should mention that I do not know if this was another planet or historic Earth.

Comment: Movie, watched it on late night TV mid to late 80s

Comment: Another detail is that everyone is human. The person in the ship in the tree is human, the leader in the castle is human, ect.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)